# Ingresar un numero en un formulario Django con un slider range

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms

Soy novato usando Django, agradezco su paciencia :). Quisiera utilizar un slider range para ingresar información en un campo NumberInput() de un formulario. De momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
models.py

monto = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Monto del préstamo', max_length=40)
```

´´´

```
forms.py
    class Meta:
    model = Formulario
    fields = '__all__'

    widgets = {
    'monto': NumberInput(
            attrs={
                'type': 'range',
                'class': 'form-range',
                'required': 'True',
                'min': '300',
                'max': '3500',
                'step': '10',
                'id': 'entrada_1',
                'oninput': 'myFunction()',
                # 'value': None
            }
        ),
```

´´´

```
      html
       <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <label for="customRange3" class="form-label">{{ form.monto.label }}</label>
                    {{ form.monto }}
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
                    <strong id="salida_1" style="font-size: x-large; font-weight:bold">$1900</strong>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

´´´

El form se renderiza sin problemas pero salen advertencias de que no se ha ingresado nada en el campo. Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir siempre un poco de css y javascript extra a tus templates o forms, puedes hacer eso de varias formas, inclusive dentro del mismo template, puedes fijarte como lo hace en [este tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp), y adaptar a lo que necesites.

Ahora mismo donde esta el `{{form.monto}}` te renderiza el input con los atributos que colocaste, si agregas el css y javascript suficiente creo que no tendrás problemas.

**Obs.: No estoy seguro si definiste la función myFunction() entre los atributos de tu widget.**

Suerte!